# Set div width the same as it's content using css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a `DIV` that changes it's width according to it's content. How is this possible?

Here's my code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="more-info-dropdown-div">
   <div id="advanced-features-more-dropdown" class="more-info-dropdown-div-label" >
    <span>Show more advanced features</span>
       <img class="more-info-dropdown-div-arrow" src="default-images/infos-arrow.png"/>
   </div>   
</div>
```

here the **CSS**:

```
.more-info-dropdown-div {
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 -6px 12px -8px #bdbdbd;
box-shadow: 0 -6px 12px -8px #bdbdbd;
text-align: center;
line-height: 25px;
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.more-info-dropdown-div-label {
background: #fafafa;
padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.more-info-dropdown-div-arrow {
margin-left: 20px;
}

.more-info-dropdown-div-label:hover more-info-dropdown-div-arrow{margin-top:8px;}
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7GA45/

Comment: Just don't put a width on it :P

Comment: i need the parent to be 100% of the page but not the child, and there's no width in it's style

Comment: with width:auto; nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7GA45/6/)**

**CSS:**

```
 .more-info-dropdown-div-label {
        background: #fafafa;
        padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 20px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
        border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: auto;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes in your code. Check the following link. You can use `dispaly: inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/7GA45/4/

Comment: with your code, the result is different from what i need